# How do I make sure my DNS and domain routing is done properly on Route 53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, ip, amazon-route53

I recently created a new domain on GoDaddy to which I want to move my current website.
I decided to move the hosting to AWS and create an EC2 Instance there.

Everything was going fine until I purchased the new domain I want to move my website to and started configuring Route 53.

I ended up following a tutorial that said to move the GoDaddy records to Route53 where I had created a hosted zone, so i started doing exactly that. However, the A record pointed to "parked", the 'www' cname record pointed to @ and a '_domainconnect' cname record pointed to _domainconnect.gd.domaincontrol.com'

When creating the new records on Route 53, I changed the 'www' cname record by making it point to my domain 'example.com' so that the www.example.com points to example.com.
I changed the A record so that it points to the IPv4 address on my instance.
Finally, I did not copy the "_domainconnect' record because I thought this was something that had to do with GoDaddy specifically and probably shouldn't be copied (I also did not see it in any tutorial).

Now, there was no problem accessing the website through the www.example.com or example.com domains but after reading multiple tutorials and watching multiple videos, there are 2 things I want to make sure I am doing right:

1- Somebody mentioned the server serving www.example.com and example.com twice and them being 2 separate versions when the previous process is done... I didn't understand what they meant and if this was a problem or not. If someone could clarify this, that would be awesome.

2- Somebody also mentioned using Elastic IPs for Route53 because the instance IPv4 might change? Is that something I should be worrying about if I will be running a website on the instance?

Sorry for the long explanation, I am trying to be as descriptive as possible.

This is the Route 53 Configuration:
[image]

Comment: With ` www.example.com` record, you set it to to `Alias`?

Comment: 2. Yes if your ec2 instance is to be restarted (which giving sometime will be restarted) then you will get assigned a new IP. The Elastic IP gives you a static IP that you can use, or reuse (not in combination) on different services (like EC2 or even better elastic load balancer when you want to serve your site from multiple EC2 instances)

Comment: @Marcin No, none of the records are set to alias

Answer (score 0):

To better understand point one, if you could attach the route 53 configuration the could hep us giving a better answer.

For the second point, two recommendations.

1. it is better if you create an Elastic IP and attach to a network interface, then attach the network interface to the instance. In this way the IP would stay forever (or as long as you want). Otherwise, as soon as you restart the instance, and this can definitively happen, you will loose the IP, therefore your DNS needs to be propagated again.
2. leave everything as it is, but as a further step learn what an AWS VPC is, it will give you much benefit rather than exposing your instance directly to the internet.

Comment: Since I can't post a picture to a comment, I added the configuration to the main post. I will also look into VPCs.

Comment: Could you explain a little more or send a link about the Elastic IPs because I understand what you mean but not how to implement it: like where do I create the Elastic IP and how to I add the network interface as the middle man?

Comment: I checked my EC2 instance and it is already connected to the default VPC that I have... Do I have to create another VPC?

Comment: that's good, no need of other VPC, the only thing that you have to do, if you haven't already done, is to go in Network & Security -> Elastic IP -> Allocate Elastic Address. Then choose associate elastic IP and in the page as a first choice you can choose between Instance or Network Interface.

Comment: I did that, I connected it to the interface directly.. is this fine or should I be adding the network interface in between?